RC Filter Analysis
Let the following circuit:

I was looking at some old youtube videos, explaining how obscure this simple looking circuit, here is my question, suppose that the AC voltage source \$ v_i(t) = A \sin(\omega t) \$, I want to understand how this circuit works when \$ \omega \neq \frac{1}{RC}\$, so what I did is find the expression of \$ v_o\$, using basic KVL and laplace's transform, I done this: \$v_o (t) + RC \frac{dv_o}{dt} = A\sin(\omega t) \\ \$
** EDIT **
Using sir Periblepsis approach of annihilators :
\$[D+\frac{1}{\tau}] v_o = A \sin(\omega t) \iff [D^2 + \omega^2][D+\frac{1}{\tau}] v_o = 0 \$
First lets do a quick proof :
\$
\begin{align*}
[D^2 + a^2][D+b] f(t) = 0 \implies f(t) = A_0 \exp{(-bt)} + A_1 \cos{at} + A_2 \sin{at}
\end{align*}
 \$
I will use a formula i think its true : \$ \prod_{i=1}^n [D+a_i] \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n e^{-a_k t} = 0\$
So \$ \begin{align*}
[D^2 + a^2][D+b] f(t) = 0 \iff [D+ia][D-ia][D+b] f(t) = 0 \end{align*} \$
\$\begin{align*}
\implies f(t) = Ae^{-bt} + Be^{iat} + Ce^{-iat} 
\end{align*}\$
\$ \begin{align*} = Ae^{-bt} + \frac{B+C}{2} [e^{iat}+e^{-iat}] + \frac{B-C}{2}[e^{iat}-e^{-iat}] \end{align*} \$ \$ \begin{align*} = A_0 e^{-bt} + A_1 \cos(at) + A_2 \sin(at) 
\end{align*}
 \$
Thus : \$ \begin{align*} v_o(t=0) = 0 = A_0 + A_1 \land  \frac{\partial v_o}{\partial t} (0) = 0 = A_2 \omega - \frac{A_0}{\tau} \land \end{align*} \$ \$ \begin{align*}  |v_o(t \rightarrow \infty)|^2 = 0 = A_1 ^2 + A_2^2 \end{align*} \$

Is alpha, beta, and gamma supposed to be a constant from some sort of fraction decomposition?

I think so yes, they are constant is there something variable there? @Colin

It's been a rather long time since I've done differential equations, Laplace Transforms, etc. but if I remember correctly, I'm sure the Laplace Transform of $ RC \cfrac{dv_o}{dt} $ is supposed to be $RC(sV_o(s) - v_c(0))$ where $v_c(0)$ is the initial voltage of the capacitor at $t=0$.

yes i've done all those calculations, more importantly i want a closed form in the domain time of the behavior of the voltage across the capacitor @Colin

@KnowledgeSeeker The driving function (source voltage over time) has a Laplace equivalent. That equivalent is not just $A$. Seems like you think it may be. But I'm not sure.

@KnowledgeSeeker Colin is right about the way Laplace handles initial value for nth order terms. In this case the 1st order includes that vc(0) part. See the link i provide in the answer below, pointing to another answer I wrote a while back, that shows exactly what Colin is taking about. The questioner there made a mistake in forgetting about it. Adding it back in gets the right result. I'll +1 your question. Someone else may help you better than me.

Hello sir @periblepsis long time no see, i hope you are doing great, well, let me clear up something, no I didnt assume that the Laplace transform of the source voltage is just $ A $ instead i clearly wrote that it is $A \frac{\omega}{s^2+ \omega^2} $ and for the initial value of the capacitor's voltage i assumed it was discharged to its zero. Thanks

Circuit:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
KCL:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_{_\text{OUT}}}{R_1}+C_1\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}V_{_\text{OUT}}&=\frac{V_{_\text{IN}}}{R_1}
\\\\
\frac{V_{_\text{OUT}}}{R_1\,C_1}+\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}V_{_\text{OUT}}&=\frac{V_{_\text{IN}}}{R_1\,C_1}
\\\\
\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac1{R_1\,C_1}\right]V_{_\text{OUT}}&=\frac{V_{_\text{IN}}}{R_1\,C_1}
\end{align*}$$
Setting \$\tau=R_1\,C_1\$ and replacing for \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$:
$$\begin{align*}
\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac1{\tau}\right]V_{_\text{OUT}}&=\frac1{\tau}V_{_\text{IN}}=\frac{A\sin\left(\omega \,t\right)}{\tau}\tag{1}\label{eq1}
\end{align*}$$
That's inhomogeneous. Use an annihilator:
$$\begin{align*}
\left[\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\right)^2+\omega^2\right]\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac1{\tau}\right]V_{_\text{OUT}}&=\left[\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\right)^2+\omega^2\right]\frac{A\sin\left(\omega \,t\right)}{\tau}
\\\\
\left[\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\right)^2+\omega^2\right]\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}+\frac1{\tau}\right]V_{_\text{OUT}}&=0
\end{align*}$$
And that's homogeneous.
The general form of the solution is now:
$$\begin{align*}
v_{out}&=A_0\exp\left(\frac{-1}{\tau}t\right)+A_1\cos\left(\omega\,t\right)+A_2\sin\left(\omega\,t\right)
\end{align*}$$
Call the initial voltage on the capacitor as \$V_{_{\text{C}_0}}\$. For example, if the capacitor starts out uncharged, then \$V_{_{\text{C}_0}}=0\:\text{V}\$ at \$t=0\$.
In general, \$A_0+A_1=V_{_{\text{C}_0}}\$. The rate of change in the voltage at \$t=0\$ helps develop \$A_0-A_2\cdot\omega\cdot\tau=V_{_{\text{C}_0}}\$. And at \$t\to\infty\$ the peak magnitude must be \$A_1^2+A_2^2=\frac{A^2}{1+\left(\omega\,\tau\right)^2}\$. (The cosine is orthogonal to the sine.)
Solve those simultaneously and you are done.
The Laplace transfer function is \$\frac{V_{_\text{OUT}}}{V_{_\text{IN}}}=\frac{\frac1{\tau}}{s+\frac1{\tau}}\$.
Note the similarity of the divisor here when comparing it with the factor on the left side of equation \$\ref{eq1}\$ above. There's a good reason why. Re-arranging, you get \$\left[s+\frac1{\tau}\right]V_{_\text{OUT}}=\frac1{\tau}V_{_\text{IN}}\$.
The whole thing can also be solved, accommodating initial factors too, in the Laplace domain before performing an inverse Laplace of the result. See here for such an example.
Note: The sine and cosine function terms can be combined into a single function term with an added phase.
Here's an LTspice run using several different starting conditions for the capacitor's initial voltage. The run provides your circuit plus a behavioral voltage source that depends entirely upon the solution formula. You can see that they are the same in all regards:


If you need further help, just ask. I tried to keep it mathematically direct and terse. But there may be parts you need to bridge over the steps I took. For example, try to apply the annihilator I used to your input function. You should be able to see why it forces a zero result. Annihilators for any function can be found looking at a Laplace table.

Amazing answer, accepted, thanks i will try to digest this

@KnowledgeSeeker I'll add an LTspice run that should confirm what I wrote and also show the simultaneous solution of the three constants.

Thank you so much sir periblepsis, i would like to know how you did the jump from the annihilator to the s-domain, also how you got the third relation corelating the squares of the coefficients, infinite thanks

@KnowledgeSeeker Perhaps you should write up a second question, referencing this one and calling out these specific questions. Your first question here, by itself, is both completely obvious (needing no explanation) or else requires a longer explanation than I can write in a comment. Your second question here is easy. The Laplace transfer function shows you. $\frac{V_{\text{OUT}}}{V{_\text{IN}}}=\frac{\frac1{\tau}}{s+\frac1{\tau}}=\frac1{s\tau+1}$. Assume $s=j\omega$, where $\sigma=0$. Then $\frac1{j\omega\tau+1}$. What is the denominator's magnitude?

@KnowledgeSeeker I will add this. I noted that  $\left[s+\frac1{\tau}\right]V_{\text{OUT}}=\frac1{\tau}V{\text{IN}}$. Note also that  $\left[s^2+\omega^2\right]\left[s+\frac1{\tau}\right]V{\text{OUT}}=\left[s^2+\omega^2\right]\frac1{\tau}V{_\text{IN}}=0$, for your case of the input source. s is just the derivative operator, remember?

Thank you so much sir periblepsis, i've wrote this question in mathstackexchange because i think its more mathematical than it has physics side, also quick check, does $ \frac{dV_{out}}{dt} (0) = 0 $? infinite thanks here is the link the the post of math.SE if you want to follow back there : "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4970724/annihilators-laplace-transform"

@KnowledgeSeeker If you read back through what I wrote, please find this: "The rate of change in the voltage at $t=0$ helps develop $A_0-A_2\cdot\omega\cdot\tau=V_{_{\text{C}_0}}$." That's where I already answer your question about the rate of change of Vout at t=0. And no, it's not always zero.

but you've applied a derivative operation on both sides of that equation before getting that formula no?

@KnowledgeSeeker Have you tried, already, to take the derivative of the general form, then substituting in zero for time? Now consider the initial voltage on the capacitor. It flows immediately out of that.

cant lie honestly, im still stuck on finding the general form already, but no i dont think it follows immediately that the rate of change of the output voltage at t = 0, is zero.

@KnowledgeSeeker Oh. I see. You don't immediately see the general form flowing out of the homogeneous equation? If that's not obvious, then that's the problem. Would you like a book and chapter reference to help out? Or?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
